# concatenate the values of dictionary into single string or sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a dictionary called self.__sequences reads like "ID:DNA sequence", and the following is part of that dictionary

```
{'1111758': ('TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAA\n', ''), 
'1111762': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGA\n', ''),
'1111763': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCCTT\n', '') }
```

I want to concatenate the values of the dictionary into one single string or sequence (no \n and no ""), that is, I want something like

```
"TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAAAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGAAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCCTT"
```

I write the following code, however, it does not give what I want. I guess it is because the value has two elements(DNA sequence and ""). I am struggling improving my code. Can anyone help me to make it work?

```
def sequence_statistics(self):
    total_len=self.__sequences.values()[0]
    for i in range(len(self.__sequences)):
        total_len += self.__sequences.values()[i]
    return total_len
```

Comment: What does it give you instead of what you want?

Comment: something like   ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGA\n', '', 'TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAA\n', '')

Comment: but i want something like this: "TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAAAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGAAGAGTTT"

Comment: Do you need them ordered by the order of the keys? (`.values()` will give you some arbitrary order of items, probably not what you expect, because dicts have no internal order.) Are the keys all strings of the same length? (If not, ordering them won't get you numerical order, but lexical order so "3" comes after "1111763").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'1111758': ('TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAA\n', ''),
... '1111762': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGA\n', ''),
... '1111763': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCCTT\n', '') }
>>>
>>> lis = []
>>> for tup in d.values():
...     lis.append(tup[0].rstrip('\n'))
...
>>> ''.join(lis)
  'AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGAAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCCTTTTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAA'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will iterate over the sorted keys of your sequences, extract the first value of the tuples in the dict and strip whitespaces. Mind that `dicts` are unordered in Python 2.7:

```
''.join(d[k][0].strip() for k in sorted(self.__sequences))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a generator that yields the first element of each value, with the "\n" stripped off:

```
(value[0].strip() for value in self.__sequences.values())
```

Since you probably want them sorted by keys, it becomes slightly more complicated:

```
(value[0].strip() for key, value in sorted(self.__sequences.items()))
```

And to turn that into a single string joined by '' (empty strings) in between, do:

```
''.join(value[0].strip() for key, value in sorted(self.__sequences.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
return "".join(v[0].strip() for k, v in self.__sequences.items())
```